# Kafka Producer retries configuration throwing ClusterAuthorizationException

Tags: apache-kafka

I want my Kafka Producer to attempt retry 3 times and then throw error after exhausting the retry attempts. When the set the **retries** >0, it starts throwing `ClusterAuthorizationException.`

Config file:-

```
`public `ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory(){`
Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("acks", "all");
props.put("retries", 3);
props.put("retry.backoff.ms", 1000);
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
`props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");`
`return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);``
```

}

Service:-

```
`KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate(producerFactory);
ListenableFuture> future = kafkaTemplate.send("my_topic", "my_key", "my_value");
future.get();`
```

The above code works fine when retries=0 but when its greater than 0, it throws `ClusterAuthorizationException.`